# Changing color of particular text in a text field

Tags: actionscript-3, text

Consider I have the text

```
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Now, this text is in a dynamic text field. I do not want to change the color of the whole field. just made fox red and dog blue.

How, can I do that in AS3. Have been looking around without no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you use the method `myTextField.setTextFormat()` you can add arguments to it to specify what part of the String that it should apply to.

F.e.

```
myTextField.setTextFormat (myFormat, 5, 8);
```

will apply to characters 5-8.

So what you need to do is to make a new TextFormat with the color you want and `setTextFormat()` those characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some HTML tags to format the text (or subset of it) inside your textField.